# Why is this HTML table not 508 compliant?

Tags: html, section508

So I ran one of my pages source code through a 508 compliance checker online, and it came back saying some of my tables are not correct, I followed the guidelines to use the scope setting but it still fails:

```
<table>

    <tr bgcolor="#f6f7f7">
        <td scope="col">adsf</td>
        <td scope="col">Type</td>
        <td scope="col">&nbsp;Check ID</td>
        <td scope="col">&nbsp;Check Title</td>
    </tr>

    <tr bgcolor="#EEEEEE" onMouseOver="javascript: this.style.backgroundColor='#FFF8DC';" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#EEEEEE';">
        <td scope="row" id="statuscell0">aad</td>
        <td align="center" id="statuscell0">OVAL</td>
        <td align="left" id="statuscell0">asdfasdf</td>
        <td align="left" id="statuscell0">asdfasdf</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- More such table rows here ... //-->
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you would need to add table headers `<th>`

Comment: do <th> tags have all the same attributes that can be used as in td's i.e, can I just go modify the headers i have in my <td's to <th ... instead of <td ...

Answer (score 2):

you need to add, summary, caption, thead, th, tfoot, tbody

Comment: Didn't think summary,caption,tfoot,thead,tbody are mandatory for compliance, just recommended

Answer (score 1):

Also I don't know whether that inline onmouseover will fly. To be accessible it will need to do the equivalent action when the row is selected by a user tabbing through the document--which won't just work without some tweaking. You need some cue that the row is highlighted even if you are not using a mouse.